# C++ : Duda con un output

Tags: c++

soy nuevo en C++ y intentando hacer un ejercicio que me propusieron en mi curso me encontre con el siguiente problema: ¿Porque despues de imprimir el vector aparece un arroba?.
Adjunto mi codigo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char letras1[] = {'a','b','c','d','e'};
    char letras2[] = {'f','g','h','i','j'};
    char letras3[10];

    for (int i = 0;i<10;i++){
        if (i <5){      
            letras3[i] = letras1[i];
        }
        else{
            letras3[i] = letras2[i-5];
        }

    }   
    cout<<letras3;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

output:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Reproduje tu código y no veo el símbolo de @, tal vez una captura de pantalla ayude un poco para que los demás usuarios te puedan ayudar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ¿Por qué después de imprimir el vector aparece un arroba?

Porque no pusiste un carácter de finalización de cadena: `\0`.

---

Cuando imprimes por consola una cadena de caracteres, se irá imprimiendo hasta que encuentre un final de cadena (representado por el [carácter nulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character)) incluso si el final de cadena está fuera de la cadena misma.

Te ha aparecido una arroba como te podía haber aparecido cualquier otro carácter, acceder a datos fuera del ámbito de una formación es un [comportamiento indefinido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido). Para evitar que pase, reserva un espacio más a tu formación e inicialízala:

```
char letras1[] = {'a','b','c','d','e'};
char letras2[] = {'f','g','h','i','j'};
char letras3[11] = { 0 }; // 11 elementos: 10 letras + 1 final de cadena.
//                   ^ <--- Todos los elementos (11) se inicializan a 0.
```

Answer (score -1):

Creo que te arroja un residuo que tiene el tercer vector. Pues lo declaras para contener 11 objetos y no 10. Intenta cambiar la declaración del vector: letras3[10] -vector con 11 elementos- por uno con 10 elementos o sea: letras3[9]. Recuerda que si no tocas nada en la configuración del compilador este tiene siempre un elemento más del numero declarado.

Comment: ¿ Estas diciendo que `char[10]` en realidad reserva espacio para **`11`** elementos ? Tantos años y me entero ahora :-O

Comment: @Trauma ¿Te rebautizamos a Trollma?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Hombre, si voy a dar por errados las bases mínimas de mis conocimientos, quisiera estar seguro. Tengo una edad ya ...

Comment: [¬  ¬](https://aha.com)

Comment: Antes de responder, escribí: creo que... Voy a explicar algunas cosas. Es la primera vez que me entero que existe esta página, me parece una genialidad. Pero también no he programado en C++ nunca. Tengo mis años y hace muchos que no programo nada.

Comment: He vuelvo a ver si puedo retomar la costumbre de programar. En mi época, con otros lenguajes no tan diferentes como C me enseñaron que las variables además de declararlas se debían inicializar. En ese tiempo era común hacerlo para evitar lo que señala PaperBirdMaster. No sabía que ahora se declaran las variables con la cantidad de elementos tal cual se necesitan. Antes no era así, o por lo menos no lo era en los lenguajes que me enseñaron.

Comment: Lo llamaban como señala Paper pero en ingles: undefined behavor. Interesado por la pregunta y leyendo a otro usuario responder que a el no le ocurría lo mismo con el mismo còdigo estuve leyendo un poco. Encontré algo parecido pero en C#; y también es semejante a lo señalado por PaperBirdMaster; los tipos char por defecto cargan \0 (U+0000). No sabía que los vectores se definen con los elementos desde 1 en adelante. Por eso supuse o creí que lo que le pasaba al programa era eso; un volcado de memoria con residuo por no inicializarlo. Disculpen.

Comment: No se si se pueden publicar direcciones de otros sitios o si viola alguna norma. Esta es la página donde hay información sobre el asunto, según creo. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/default-values-table

Comment: Me gustaría preguntarle a PaperBirdMaster: ¿por qué razón el usuario que copió el código no obtuvo la misma salida?

Comment: Estoy preguntando sin haber programado nunca en C++. No entiendo la razón porque un mismo código -si es que tienen el mismo compilador con los mismos pases de argumentos- producen resultados diferentes. Es raro para mi que ocurra eso, a pesar de la respuesta de PaperBirdMaster.

Comment: @user141864 Bienvenido al sitio. Creo que mi comentario fue muy *troll*, me disculpo por ello. ¿ Te has pasado por [el centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) ? Tiene un montón de información interesante y útil. De entrada, aquí no funcionamos como un foro cualquiera. Se esperan preguntas correctas, y proporcionamos respuestas lo más técnicas posibles. En otras palabras: intentamos responder si sabemos la respuesta. Se premia las buenas respuestas y se *castiga* a las malas.

Comment: @user141864 el usuario que copió el código no obtuvo la misma salida porque el acceder a memoria fuera de una formación es comportamiento indefinido. El motivo real un poco más complejo y técnico, tanto que no se puede responder en un comentario. Te animo a redactar una pregunta sobre el tema si quieres más detalles.